# Backup de VisualStudioCode

Tags: vscode

Muy buenas tardes.

Espero que se encuentren muy bien.

El motivo por el que les escribo es para saber si existe un metodo o forma de hacer un respaldo de las configuraciones y extenciones que tengo en Visual Studio Code, ya que pienso restaurar mi equipo de fabrica y quisiera mantener tal y como esta mi VSC para una vez vuelto a cargar el sistema operativo, ya que hay unas configuraciones que no recuerdo como las hice.

Sin más me despido de ustedes, esperando que tengan un excelente dia.

Comment: Yo tengo la configuración de VSCode sincronizada con mi cuenta de Microsoft, si desinstalo y vuelvo a instalar solo debo importar la configuración de la cuenta, lee [sincronización de configuración](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/ide/synchronized-settings-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022#synchronized-settings)